# VBA - Trying to add a range between two strings as a series to a graph

Tags: vba, excel, charts, multiple-columns

I'm trying to write a macro which will add a large number of datapoints as a new series to a chart in excel.

I currently import voltammogram data from a csv file to the spreadsheet into two columns (Potential and Current). This data is made of 43 cycles containing between 500 and 1500 values each (I have no control over how many points the software spits out, which complicates things).

I would like to scan the data for a string which appears at the start of each cycle "Potential*" and at the end of each cycle "*PN*", add these values to the chart and then move on to the next cycle.

I've combined a few different solutions from different searches to get a messy solution that works sometimes but not always; I'm fairly confident it would work if each cycle contained the same number of points but that's unfortunately not the case.

My messy solution:

```
Sub InsertChart()

Dim first As Long, last As Long
first = 4
last = Range(Range("A:A").Find("*Potential*").Offset(1), Range("A:A").Find("*PN*", Range("A:A").Find("*Potential*")).Offset(-1, 1)).Cells.Count


Dim wsChart As Worksheet
Set wsChart = Sheets(1)

wsChart.Activate
wsChart.Shapes.AddChart.Select

Dim chart As chart
Set chart = ActiveChart
chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    ActiveChart.ClearToMatchStyle
    ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 240
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 0
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 1.5
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 0.1

' adding series
chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Cycle 01"
chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & first & ":$A$" & last
chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & first & ":$B$" & last

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Cycle 02"
chart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 2) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 3
chart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 2) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 3

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "Cycle 03"
chart.SeriesCollection(3).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 3) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 4
chart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 3) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 4

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(4).Name = "Cycle 04"
chart.SeriesCollection(4).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 4) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 5
chart.SeriesCollection(4).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 4) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 5

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(5).Name = "Cycle 05"
chart.SeriesCollection(5).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 5) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 6
chart.SeriesCollection(5).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 5) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 6

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(6).Name = "Cycle 06"
chart.SeriesCollection(6).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 6) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 7
chart.SeriesCollection(6).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 6) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 7

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(7).Name = "Cycle 07"
chart.SeriesCollection(7).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 7) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 8
chart.SeriesCollection(7).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 7) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 8

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(8).Name = "Cycle 08"
chart.SeriesCollection(8).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 8) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 9
chart.SeriesCollection(8).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 8) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 9

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(9).Name = "Cycle 09"
chart.SeriesCollection(9).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 9) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 10
chart.SeriesCollection(9).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 9) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 10

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(10).Name = "Cycle 10"
chart.SeriesCollection(10).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 10) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 11
chart.SeriesCollection(10).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 10) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 11

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(11).Name = "Cycle 11"
chart.SeriesCollection(11).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 11) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 12
chart.SeriesCollection(11).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 11) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 12

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(12).Name = "Cycle 12"
chart.SeriesCollection(12).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 12) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 13
chart.SeriesCollection(12).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 12) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 13

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(13).Name = "Cycle 13"
chart.SeriesCollection(13).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 13) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 14
chart.SeriesCollection(13).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 13) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 14

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(14).Name = "Cycle 14"
chart.SeriesCollection(14).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 14) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 15
chart.SeriesCollection(14).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 14) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 15

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(15).Name = "Cycle 15"
chart.SeriesCollection(15).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 15) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 16
chart.SeriesCollection(15).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 15) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 16

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(16).Name = "Cycle 16"
chart.SeriesCollection(16).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 16) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 17
chart.SeriesCollection(16).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 16) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 17

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(17).Name = "Cycle 17"
chart.SeriesCollection(17).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 17) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 18
chart.SeriesCollection(17).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 17) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 18

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(18).Name = "Cycle 18"
chart.SeriesCollection(18).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 18) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 19
chart.SeriesCollection(18).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 18) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 19

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(19).Name = "Cycle 19"
chart.SeriesCollection(19).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 19) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 20
chart.SeriesCollection(19).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 19) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 20

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(20).Name = "Cycle 20"
chart.SeriesCollection(20).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 20) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 21
chart.SeriesCollection(20).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 20) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 21

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(21).Name = "Cycle 21"
chart.SeriesCollection(21).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 21) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 22
chart.SeriesCollection(21).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 21) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 22

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(22).Name = "Cycle 22"
chart.SeriesCollection(22).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 22) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 23
chart.SeriesCollection(22).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 22) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 23

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(23).Name = "Cycle 23"
chart.SeriesCollection(23).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 23) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 24
chart.SeriesCollection(23).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 23) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 24

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(21).Name = "Cycle 24"
chart.SeriesCollection(21).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 24) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 25
chart.SeriesCollection(21).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 24) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 25

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(25).Name = "Cycle 25"
chart.SeriesCollection(25).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 25) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 26
chart.SeriesCollection(25).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 25) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 26

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(26).Name = "Cycle 26"
chart.SeriesCollection(26).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 26) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 27
chart.SeriesCollection(26).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 26) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 27

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(27).Name = "Cycle 27"
chart.SeriesCollection(27).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 27) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 28
chart.SeriesCollection(27).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 27) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 28

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(28).Name = "Cycle 28"
chart.SeriesCollection(28).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 28) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 29
chart.SeriesCollection(28).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 28) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 29

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(29).Name = "Cycle 29"
chart.SeriesCollection(29).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 29) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 30
chart.SeriesCollection(29).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 29) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 30

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(30).Name = "Cycle 30"
chart.SeriesCollection(30).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 30) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 31
chart.SeriesCollection(30).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 30) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 31

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(31).Name = "Cycle 31"
chart.SeriesCollection(31).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 31) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 32
chart.SeriesCollection(31).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 31) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 32

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(32).Name = "Cycle 32"
chart.SeriesCollection(32).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 32) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 33
chart.SeriesCollection(32).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 32) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 33

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(33).Name = "Cycle 33"
chart.SeriesCollection(33).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 33) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 34
chart.SeriesCollection(33).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 33) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 34

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(34).Name = "Cycle 34"
chart.SeriesCollection(34).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 34) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 35
chart.SeriesCollection(34).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 34) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 35

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(35).Name = "Cycle 35"
chart.SeriesCollection(35).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 35) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 36
chart.SeriesCollection(35).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 35) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 36

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(36).Name = "Cycle 36"
chart.SeriesCollection(36).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 36) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 37
chart.SeriesCollection(36).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 36) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 37

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(37).Name = "Cycle 37"
chart.SeriesCollection(37).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 37) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 38
chart.SeriesCollection(37).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 37) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 38

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(38).Name = "Cycle 38"
chart.SeriesCollection(38).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 38) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 39
chart.SeriesCollection(38).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 38) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 39

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(39).Name = "Cycle 39"
chart.SeriesCollection(39).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 39) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 40
chart.SeriesCollection(39).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 39) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 40

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(40).Name = "Cycle 40"
chart.SeriesCollection(40).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 40) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 41
chart.SeriesCollection(40).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 40) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 41

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(41).Name = "Cycle 41"
chart.SeriesCollection(41).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 41) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 42
chart.SeriesCollection(41).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 41) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 42

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(42).Name = "Cycle 42"
chart.SeriesCollection(42).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 42) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 43
chart.SeriesCollection(42).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 42) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 43

chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
chart.SeriesCollection(43).Name = "Cycle 43"
chart.SeriesCollection(43).XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & (last * 43) + 4 & ":$A$" & last * 44
chart.SeriesCollection(43).Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$B$" & (last * 43) + 4 & ":$B$" & last * 44
End Sub
```

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be great.

After using your help, I've updated the macro to use your code and it's almost there. It's only the Y values (Current) that get output as 0s but I feel like that may be my fault during tweaking the code to make it work with the data.

```
'Plots the Excel Data
Sub Voltammogram()

'Add Chart
Dim wsChart As Worksheet
Set wsChart = Sheets(1)

wsChart.Activate
wsChart.Shapes.AddChart.Select

Dim chart As chart
    Set chart = ActiveChart
Dim chartsize As Range
    Set chartsize = ActiveSheet.Range("D1:o20")
Dim Chart_obj As ChartObject
    Set Chart_obj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)

chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
chart.HasTitle = True
chart.ChartTitle.Text = ActiveSheet.Name
chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Text = "Potential (V)"
chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Text = "Current (uA)"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 0
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 1.5
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 0.1
ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 240
Chart_obj.Height = chartsize.Height
Chart_obj.Width = chartsize.Width
Chart_obj.Top = chartsize.Top
Chart_obj.Left = chartsize.Left
ActiveChart.ChartArea.ClearContents

'Find Last Row
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    Cells(LastRow + 2, 1).Value = "PN"
    Cells(LastRow + 4, 1).Value = "END"

'End of Data Flag
Dim End_of_data As Boolean
End_of_data = False

'Chart Object
'Dim Chart_obj As ChartObject
Set Chart_obj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)

'Series Variable
Dim MySeries As Series
Dim Series_Col As SeriesCollection
Set Series_Col = Chart_obj.chart.SeriesCollection

'Range Offset Variable
Dim i As Integer
i = 3

'Series Index Value
Dim si As Integer
si = 1

'Value Variables
Dim Voltage, Current As String

'Value Collections
Dim Vol_List As New Collection
Dim Cur_List As New Collection

'Looping through the Sheet collecting Cycle data
While (End_of_data = False)

    Voltage = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value
    Current = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(i, 1).Value

    'Checking for a Cycle End
    If (Voltage = "PN") Then
        'Incrementing the series index at the end of cycle
        si = si + 1

        'Creating the Series with all of the cycle data
        Set MySeries = Series_Col.NewSeries
        MySeries.Values = Collection_To_Array(Cur_List)
        MySeries.XValues = Collection_To_Array(Vol_List)
        MySeries.Name = "Cycle " & (si - 1)


        'Clearing out the List
         Set Vol_List = New Collection
         Set Cur_List = New Collection

    'Checking for end of data. This assumes there are no blanks in your data collection. You may need to update this logic
    ElseIf (Voltage = "END") Then

        'Exiting the Loop
        End_of_data = True
    Else

        'Adding the Data to the List
        If (Voltage <> "Potential" And Voltage <> "PN") Then
            Vol_List.Add (Voltage)
            Cur_List.Add (Current)
        End If
    End If


    'Incrementing the offset Counter
    i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub

Function Collection_To_Array(c As Collection) As Variant()
    Length = c.Count - 1
    Dim A() As Variant
    ReDim A(Length)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Length + 1
        A(i - 1) = c.Item(i)        'Arrays are zero based and collections are 1 based
    Next
    Collection_To_Array = A
End Function
```

Edit: Turns out the problem of Y values appearing as 0 was caused by me forgetting to switch Dim Voltage, Current to Dim Current, Voltage. The new problem is that values are being recorded and are visible in "view data" on the graph but aren't being plotted, there's also an overflow error after 21 cycles (around 30000 datapoints). I think the invisible plots are caused by empty cells which I should be able to fix but I can't find the source of the overflow.

```
'Plots the Excel Data
Sub Voltammogram()

'Add Chart
Dim chart As chart
Dim chartsize As Range
Dim Chart_obj As ChartObject
Dim VolMin As Double
    VolMin = WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("A:A"))
Dim VolMax As Double
    VolMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A:A"))

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    Set chart = ActiveChart
    Set chartsize = ActiveSheet.Range("D1:O20")
    Set Chart_obj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
    chart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    chart.HasTitle = True
    chart.ChartTitle.Text = ActiveSheet.Name
    chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Text = "Potential (V)"
    chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Text = "Current (uA)"
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = VolMin
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = VolMax
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 0.1
    ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 240
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelPosition = xlLow
    Chart_obj.Height = chartsize.Height
    Chart_obj.Width = chartsize.Width
    Chart_obj.Top = chartsize.Top
    Chart_obj.Left = chartsize.Left
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.ClearContents

'Find Last Row
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    If Not (Cells(LastRow, 1) = "END") Then
        Cells(LastRow + 2, 1).Value = "PN"
        Cells(LastRow + 4, 1).Value = "END"
    End If

'End of Data Flag
Dim End_of_data As Boolean
End_of_data = False

'Chart Object
'Dim Chart_obj As ChartObject
'Set Chart_obj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)

'Series Variable
Dim MySeries As Series
Dim Series_Col As SeriesCollection
Set Series_Col = Chart_obj.chart.SeriesCollection

'Range Offset Variable
Dim i As Integer
i = 2

'Series Index Value
Dim si As Integer
si = 1

'Value Variables
Dim Current, Voltage As String

'Value Collections
Dim Vol_List As New Collection
Dim Cur_List As New Collection

'Looping through the Sheet collecting Cycle data
While (End_of_data = False)

    Voltage = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value
    Current = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(i, 1).Value

    'Checking for a Cycle End
    If (Voltage = "PN") Then
        'Incrementing the series index at the end of cycle
        si = si + 1

        'Creating the Series with all of the cycle data
        Set MySeries = Series_Col.NewSeries
        MySeries.Values = Collection_To_Array(Cur_List)
        MySeries.XValues = Collection_To_Array(Vol_List)
        MySeries.Name = "Cycle " & (si - 1)

        'Clearing out the List
         Set Vol_List = New Collection
         Set Cur_List = New Collection

    'Checking for end of data. This assumes there are no blanks in your data collection. You may need to update this logic
    ElseIf (Voltage = "END") Then

        'Exiting the Loop
        End_of_data = True
    Else

        'Adding the Data to the List
        If (Voltage <> "Potential" And Voltage <> "PN") Then
            Vol_List.Add (Voltage)
            Cur_List.Add (Current)
        End If
    End If


    'Incrementing the offset Counter
    i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub

Function Collection_To_Array(c As Collection) As Variant()
    c.Remove (1)
    c.Remove (c.Count)
    Length = c.Count - 1
    Dim a() As Variant
    ReDim a(Length)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Length + 1
        a(i - 1) = c.Item(i)        'Arrays are zero based and collections are 1 based
    Next
    Collection_To_Array = a

End Function
```

Comment: Do two Finds, the first to find Potential and the second to find PN (after the first found cell). Look up Find help because you should check whether the value is found before proceeding to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
    'Plots the Excel Data
Sub Plot_data()

'End of Data Flag
Dim End_of_data As Boolean
End_of_data = False

'Chart Object
Dim Chart_obj As ChartObject
Set Chart_obj = Sheet6.ChartObjects(1)

'Series Variable
Dim MySeries As Series
Dim Series_Col As SeriesCollection
Set Series_Col = Chart_obj.Chart.SeriesCollection

'Range Offset Variable
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

'Series Index Value
Dim si As Integer
si = 1

'Value Variables
Dim Voltage, Current As String

'Value Collections
Dim Vol_List As New Collection
Dim Cur_List As New Collection

'Looping through the Sheet collecting Cycle data
While (End_of_data = False)

    Voltage = Sheet6.Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).value
    Current = Sheet6.Range("A1").Offset(i, 1).value

    'Checking for a Cycle End
    If (Voltage = "PN") Then
        'Incrementing the series index at the end of cycle
        si = si + 1

        'Creating the Series with all of the cycle data
        Set MySeries = Series_Col.NewSeries
        MySeries.Values = Sheet2.Collection_To_Array(Vol_List)
        MySeries.XValues = Sheet2.Collection_To_Array(Cur_List)

        'Clearing out the List
         Set Vol_List = New Collection
         Set Cur_List = New Collection

    'Checking for end of data. This assumes there are no blanks in your data collection. You may need to update this logic
    ElseIf (Voltage = "") Then

        'Exiting the Loop
        End_of_data = True
    Else

        'Adding the Data to the List
        If (Voltage <> "Potential" And Voltage <> "PN") Then
            Vol_List.Add (Voltage)
            Cur_List.Add (Current)
        End If
    End If


    'Incrementing the offset Counter
    i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub

Function Collection_To_Array(c As Collection) As Variant()
    Length = c.Count - 1
    Dim A() As Variant
    ReDim A(Length)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Length + 1
        A(i - 1) = c.Item(i)        'Arrays are zero based and collections are 1 based
    Next
    Collection_To_Array = A
End Function
```

Comment: This might need a little tweaking based upon how your data is formatted by I was assuming you have Potentials in Column A and Currents in Column B. I tested this out and it works. The Loop assumes a blank range means the data is ended so keep this in mind. You also must have a blank chart in the excel sheet. I'd recommend a scatter chart

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. It took some tweaking to get it working with my data but it seems really close now. It can plot the X values (potentials) but the Y values all come up as 0s. Have I messed something up with the collections? I only started working in VBA recently